# Similar route mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I need to map to create controller what must response to two urls:

1. "http://localhost/api/controller?id=1" (where only id value can change)
2. "http://localhost/api/controller/anotherId/someconst" (where anotherId is the only one changing part)

i map it to such route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("Test", "api/{controller}/{id}/{someconst}", new { controller = "Test", someconst = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

And have to methods in my controller:

```
public void Get(int id) { ... }
public void Get(int anotherId, string someconst ) { ... }
```

It works...But it doesn't look nice...cause "string someconst" is not a param, it's just a const part of url. But if i remove "string someconst" param second url wouldn't work.
Is it possible to map one controller to two routes to resolve this urls to make it clear without fake param which is a const in fact?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have another action on the controller? you could say "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}" and then instead of calling it "public void Get(int anotherId, string someconst)" you could call it "public void GetSomeConst(int anotherId)". Just make sure you set your default action

Comment: I didn't understand you totally but think you are right...i found the same solution...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i've got the answer...just to have to routes...

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("Test", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { controller = "Test", action = "Get", id= @"\d+"); );

routes.MapHttpRoute("TestSomeConst", "api/{controller}/{anotherId}/someconst", new { controller = "Test", action = "GetSomeconst", anotherId= @"\d+");
```

And change controller methods (actions):

```
public void Get(int id) { ... } 
public void GetSomeconst(int anotherId) { ... }
```

Comment: Moved to an answer so I can explain better.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try doing is to map the route like this:

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute("Test", "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}", new { controller = "Test", action = "Get", id= @"\d+"} );
```

and make your actions:

```
 public void Get(int id) { ... }

 [HttpGet]
 public void Someconst(int id) { ... }
```

Because your action defaults to the "Get" method, you can ignore that and call it with:

```
 http://localhost/api/test/1
```

If you wanted to call your other method, you would use

```
 http://localhost/api/test/1/someconst
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? i completly copied you code and it doesn't... just first method fired

Comment: I changed the code a bit, I ran a simple test application and the updated code works. I was a little confused about how controller/action naming worked. For some reason I thought you wouldnt have to spell out the "get" for the getsomeconst endpoint in the request, but you do. With the "[HttpGet]" attribute you don't have to.